# Compilation Difference When Using TexLive Instead of Miktex

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texlive

I'm a long time MikTex user since I love their on-the-fly installation philosophy and tools and I'm happy with it. For job reasons I have to start to use R programming language and, for some reason, the package under dnf is dependent on TexLive distribution which, to begin with, doesn't make any sense because a package should be dependent on specific tools, not a specific LaTex distribution but, anyway...

I uninstalled MikTex and installed TexLive(full) and tried to compile a somewhat complex project which has a `Main.tex` file which includes two other files, `Title.tex` and `Body.tex`. To include the files the package subfiles is used, particularly the command `/subfileinclude{file_name.tex}`. Example source code is in [Github](https://github.com/Balrrach/latex-question).

Each of the included files begins with the following lines which indicate how each subfile must have the same 'headers' as the Main file.

```
% !TeX root = ../Main.tex

\documentclass[..]{subfiles}
```

Compilation options are:

```
pdflatex
-synctex=1
-interaction=nonstopmode
-file-line-error
-output-directory=../pdf
-aux-directory=../build
--shell-escape
Main
```

It tries to compile wrongly because it doesn't use build directory as the auxiliary directory(as stated in the compilation options) and throws compilation errors:

```
I can't write on file Title/Title.tex.aux
\@include...\immediate \openout \@partoux #1.aux

Emergency stop
\@include...\immediate \openout \@partoux #1.aux

Fatal error orcurred, no outpuet PDF file produced!
Trascript written on ../pdf/Main.log
```

When manually create Title and Body directories inside pdf directory it compiles correctly but resulting file is a blank page.

I have three question.
First, how is it possible that TexLive behaves differently than MikTex?.
Second, why is this error happening?.
And third, how(if possible) can I fix it?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of, you can only compare the two if your miktex was fully up to date. Additionally, you will need to provide a full but mk i al example that others can tests.

Comment: Thirdly, texlive does not support all the output/aux firs that miktex does (I have personally never understood the need for them)

Comment: well miktex and texlive are different and one difference is that texlive doesn't support `-aux-directory`. Beside this I have some doubts that R really requires texlive. If an external texlive works with it, an external miktex should work too. Also you don't have to uninstall miktex to use texlive, I have both and switch between the systems by changing the PATH variable.

Comment: @daleif, I can confirm that MikTex was fully up to date. @Ulrike Fischer TexLive not supporting `aux-directory` explains the fact that the build directory wasn't used. I can also confirm that at least in fedora there is a dependency on a huge amount of TexLive packages and there are conflicts between TexLive packages and MikTex packages.

Comment: R itself only needs tex to be in the path, although the linux package may set the linux texlive as a package dependency so if you want to use the upstream texlive (quite common) or linux miktex (quite rare) you just need to install stub texlive packages that keep the linux package manager happy without actually installing anything. (look on this site for questions about installing vanilla texlive on linux)

Comment: I can't install the necessary TexLive packages cause they are in conflict with MikTex packages.

Comment: I've added a link to latex source code in Github for anyone who wants to try to compile it.